# Codeigniter - Handling a form with only one controller for all pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

I started using Codeigniter in a work project, and I'm still getting the hang of it...

Going around the Codeigniter tutorials I started building the website with only one controller to handle the views, but now I can't handle the form submission on that controller. I'm losing my mind over here... :P

This is the controller's only function (pages.php)

```
    public function view($page = 'home')
    {

        if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        // handle ACTIVE class
        $current_page = uri_string();

        $this->Mp->isactiveset($this->session->userdata('active'),$current_page);
        $this->Mp->newactive($this->session->userdata('active'),$current_page);

        // testing database query and passing variables
        $passar = $this->Mp->testedb();

        // get ap types
        $aptype = $this->Mp->getaptype();

        // passing data to view
        $data['estado'] = $passar; // Testing db connection
        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Homepage page
        $data['aptypes'] = $aptype; // Ap types


        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

    }
```

i have the function to handle the form prepped

```
    public function index()
    {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome', 'Username', 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[25]|');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('telemovel', 'Telephone', 'numeric|exact_length[9]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mensagem', 'MessageBody', 'required|min_length[10]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {

        // handle ACTIVE class
        $current_page = uri_string();

        $this->Mp->isactiveset($this->session->userdata('active'),$current_page);
        $this->Mp->newactive($this->session->userdata('active'),$current_page);

        // get ap types
        $aptype = $this->Mp->getaptype();

        // testing database query and passing variables
        $passar = $this->Mp->testedb();

        // passing data to view
        $data['estado'] = $passar; // Testing db connection
        $data['aptypes'] = $aptype; // Ap types


        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
    else
    {   
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/submit', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

This is how the route.php looks like (after the first answer I now know this is relevant)

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/view";
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['(\w{2})/(.*)'] = '$2';
$route['(\w{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

On the view, when I do the form_open('submit', $attributes) it just doesn't go inside any function on my controller, except the views. Obviously I have put the form handling function on the pages.php, renamed it times over, tried different form submission pages (form_open('pages that I tried', $attributes)). How can I make it go to a specific function to handle the form submission?

Answer (score 0):

```
form_open('submit', $attributes)
```

must be

```
form_open('/path_to_my_page', $attributes)
```

if I understand you correctly ...

```
form_open('/view/page', $attributes)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it won't do what i want. I want a function in pages.php controller to handle the submission. this is not entering any function in it. this just goes to submit.php view, therefore it only uses the "public function view" funtion on my controller.

Comment: Did you make route for that submit function ?

Comment: ?... No... I think. I'm new so bare with me. How can i achieve that, please?

Comment: I did it. Just waiting to pass the time before im allowed to answer my own question. Thank you @Svetlio for pointing me the right way

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out! Thank's to Svetlio for pointing me in the right way. Here's how i did it:

**1)** Set correctly the path in the form initialization:

```
echo form_open('contactos/submit', $attributes);
```

**2)** Go to the routes configuration (application/config/**routes.php**) and add the route exception to this file

```
$route['contactos/submit'] = "pages/submit";
```

What this does is, when the program is asked for the path 'contactos/submit', it points to the function **submit** in the **pages.php** controller (That was what i was looking for...)

3) Define in your controller the function submit, to correctly handle the submission of the form

```
public function submit()
{
/* handle the form code */
    }
```